# Using rspec tags with autotest

Tags: rspec, autotest

I have a section of my test suite which runs a bunch of really slow importers. These tests don't need to be run often (unless the importers are actually being worked on) so I've split them out using Rspec tags: http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/dir/command-line/tag-option

This works great but what would be even more awesome would be if I could setup Autotest ignore the specs tagged this way be default. I can't seem to find an obvious way to do this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `--tag` option in the RSpec configuration file with a tilde to indicate specs to bypass. Autotest will execute RSpec using the values in the config file, and will pass along the `--tag` option as well.

Look for a file in your project root named `.rspec`.

Add something like `--tag ~speed:slow`

Add the tags to the slow specs:

```
it "should not run this really slow test", :speed => 'slow' do
  # blah blah
end
```

More examples can be found in [the RSpec docs](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/dir/command-line/tag-option).

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I was silly and trying to edit autotest's discover.rb file instead...